# Material bottom navigation bottom icon space bug

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I have a problem with my material bottom nav. When I have height = wrap_content the bottom nav resize if I do a click a menu item. When I have height = 56dp the btm nav goes up and that is hidden.

[gif: height = 56dp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsid6.gif)

[gif: height = wrap_content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ6nq.gif)

in my activity

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    style="@style/EfNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

my style

```
 <style name="EfNavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="itemIconTint">@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ef_field_white_50</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had in my theme:

```
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

So, I need this in my layout:

```
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```